# How can I share a session across multiple subdomains in ASP.NET in the localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc application which got multiple sub-domains, and I am sharing the session across the the sub domains.

I set `cookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieDomain = ".domain.com;"` to make it work.

But it is not working in the localhost, I set for local as

`cookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieDomain = ".localhost:1984;"`

Is there any other way to setup for localhost?

Comment: Have you configured session state as `InProc` inside `web.config` on development machine? Also, what kind of server running on development version?

Comment: Yes, it is InProc. It is IIS Express.

Comment: AFAIK, `InProc` session state resets when application pool was recycled, thus you need a unique `machineKey` shared for all state processes. You can use `machineKey` property used for deployment server in your `web.config` on development machine, or generate a new one using IIS. Other way to try is SQL Server-based session state management.

Comment: I also tried with Custom session state, which points to redis server, but not working with that too.

Comment: Which kind of custom session not worked? Provide details to the session state management you've tried on your question if necessary.